# How to disable Graphql Introspection for Public in Nestjs

Tags: security, graphql, nestjs, production

I want to make my Graphql API more secure and I am looking for a way to disable Graphql Introspection in Nestjs for Public or a way to exclude certain private APIs but haven't been able to find any reference in the Nestjs documentation,

I have AuthGuards setup but they won't serve the purpose in preventing schema access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apollo the answer is right there [in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/security/why-you-should-disable-graphql-introspection-in-production/#turning-off-introspection-in-production).

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
});
```

This disables introspection in production.

If you want to disable it always (not recommended as it makes it harder to develop):

```
introspection: false
```